# Euler characteristic = 1 iff manifod simply connected?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

let $D$ be a smooth manifold with boundary. Is it true that the Euler characteristic of $D$ is equal to 1 if and only if $D$ is simply connected? For domains in $\mathbb{R}^2$ this should be true, but I am not sure for general manifolds.

Edit: The answer below explains that this is false in general. But it is true for 2-dimensional manifolds with non-empty boundary.

Does anyone know a good source which explains such characteristics of the Euler characteristic?

Best wishes

Comment: Please do not change the question in a way which invalidates an already posted answer.

Comment: Sorry for that. I hope it is now better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is false in general. Removing $k$ open balls from $S^3$ leaves a manifold of Euler characteristic $-k$, and that manifold is simply connected because it is homotopy equivalent to removing $k-1$ points from $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Thank you. Is it maybe true for 2 dimensional manifolds with boundary?

Comment: Yes, if you are assuming that the boundary is nonempty. Otherwise the projective plane is a counterexample.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for this clarification. Do you know a reference where I can find a proof?

Comment: This is an application of the classification of surfaces.